# How can I achieve my goal with this HTML code

Tags: html, css

So I'm doing an assignment for a Course I am doing, and one part of the assignment is to "Build a website" for a pegs company.

And knowing me I'm that guy who like s to keep things organised, and to make potential troubleshooting a breeze.

To that end I had decided, when it comes to css style sheets, I would have multiple style sheets, but each style sheet covers a specific part of "my website", now I have a navbar.css and working on a "Content box.css(And because I have not learnt css fully, I have not put anything on it)

But that's not why I am here, I would like some help in better organising a specific set of content

HTML code Below

```
<html>

    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Home</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css"></link>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="content_boxes.css"></link>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#fffdd0">
        <header>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About_Us.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact_Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

            <div class="section"><h1 align="center"><span>Home</span></h1></div>

                <p h1 align="center"><img src= "https://pngimg.com/uploads/clothespin/clothespin_PNG1.png" width="100" height="100">We use renewable resources to manufacture our product consisting of plantation tree wood and recycled steel<img src= "https://pngimg.com/uploads/clothespin/clothespin_PNG1.png" width="100" height="100"></p>

        <center> 
                <div class="container">  
                        <div class="box">  
                            <div class="box-row">  
                                    <div class="box-cell box1">  
                            <h4>About Us</h4>
                                            <p class="content">Talon Textile Fasteners was formed in the same year that the colony of South Australia enacted legislation giving women the right to vote in 1894.</p>
                                    </div>

            <div class="container">  
                        <div class="box">  
                            <div class="box-row">
                        <div class="box-cell box2">
                            <h4>Products</h4>
                                            <p class="content">The company was formed on a belief that consumers had a right to use quality textile fasteners when completing one of the most fundamental tasks of modern humans.
                                    </div>  
                 
            <div class="container">  
                        <div class="box">  
                            <div class="box-row">
                                    <div class="box-cell box3">
                            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                                            <p class="content">Talon Textile Fasteners has additional resources and information available upon request. Contact us for further clarification about our business.</p>
                                    </div>  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                </div>  
            </center>

        <footer>
            <p>©2021 - Talon Textile Fasteners, a fictitious business scenario set up for educational purposes by Upskilled RTO 40374 | Privacy Policy | Copyright Policy</p>
        </footer>                       
    </body>
</html>
```

I made this on a HTML editor on my iPad and well, the page displays, but not the way I want it to, those three sections "About Us", "Products" and "Contact Us" I wanna put inside a rounded corner square, on top of that I cannot seem to get the text in those sections to not seem so narrow.

So I thought maybe someone whom is a fluent HTML user might be able to help me, and hell even provide so e css code that i can put into my "content_box.css file.

and hey, if you know of a way to "clean up" my code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So honest.. haha.. most of the developers don't have time to write CSS code from scratch.  Try something on your own and if you are blocked definitely you would get help

Comment: that question would fit better for sites as `code review`. Having multiple css-files for organisation is a no go. For organisation you have comment options. HTML: `<!-- Comment -->` and CSS: `/* Comment */` do not only organise but labeling the sections. PS: FOr organisation purpsoe it also would be a good start to keep the spacings right...

Comment: Fourth paragraph: "But that's not why I'm here."  Please respect the time others must spend in order to find out why you're here.  Stay to the point and be brief while providing the information necessary to get to the root of whatever issue you may have.

Comment: For Code review I would flag following things: Missing language tag within the head.  Background color should be added to the css not as inline style. I see no reason to nest your header that much. `<p><img></p>` I see no reason to wrap an image within an empty paragraph. `<center>` tag is otudated with the introduction of HTML5. Its an ancient HTML4 tag. Nowadays you center by using css. Overall way to many inline-style used.

Comment: @tacoshy The whole having multiple css files for specific tasks, is similar to how I sort out files on my PC, in the pictures folder there is the misc folder, in the misch folder is a folder for x, y and z, in all three of those is folders x, y and z, up untill I have a repository where I know precisely where every file is.

Comment: @tacoshy I did not know I needed a language tag, will be including one now. Am still learning css so it is most likely I am not familiar with how to do most css stuff. The whole img thing I'm still trying to come to grips with, and when I was doing the sectioning for the home page, i was copying off a site that teaches html, and they used <center> for stuff like you see in that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code:

In the CSS,

1. I have created a Nav Bar for your website.
2. Added links in navbar.
3. When the user hover on any of the links the background color turns into black color (you can change the color/background color just by changing the #code)
4. border of the button is now rounded as you said.

```css
/* CSS reset */
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* common design */
a,
li{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

/* designing header */
header{
    background-color: #0652DD;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: white;
}

/* designing main nav bar */
.main-nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

/* designing nav links */
.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-links li{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* designing nav links when a user hovers on it */
.nav-links li:hover{
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* designing nav "a" tag */
.nav-links a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <!-- creating nav bar -->
        <div class="main-nav">

            <!-- creating nav logo -->
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>LOGO</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- creating nav links -->
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

***IMAGE OF THE OUTPUT***
[image: This is the output of the following code]

> You can change the color, font size, background color as you want

I think you should learn the CSS after learning HTML because without CSS you can't design the pages, and i"ll suggest you create different pages for About Us and For Contact Us.

Comment: Umm, the navbar is not the issue, the main content is.

Comment: Ohh, Ok i'll try